# Reusing Access_Token from server in Facebook JS SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using Facebook c# SDK to authenticate user (successfully). But I want also to use FB.ui JS methods on client. Is there any way to "reuse" already received access_token from c# SDK in Facebook JS SDK? I don't want to call FB.Login because I've already authenticated user on server side.

Comment: Why not using [`FB.getLoginStatus()`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/)? at least this would insure that the user is *still* logged-in when you make an API call.

Comment: Thanks for reply. FB.getLoginStatus() always returns no auth response because I didn't call FB.login. My problem is different - I've successfully logged user "on server" using OAuth and have valid access token which I could put to some form field on client. What I need is to make some FB.ui API call without need to login him again with FB.login. If I don't login him again with FB.login, FB.ui API is working but showing dialogs in standard popup instead of nice facebook popup embedded in page. If I call FB.login I will bother user with some login redirection/popups.

Comment: This option has been done with the latest js-sdk and php sdk 3.1.1 ,where you can login using one sdk and access information from other.. Also remember Facebook doesn't have official version of C# SDK. so you have see how the latest changes have been done in the PHP SDK, so that you can rewrite your base facebook classes!

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? If so, could you share some details as to how you did it or possibly a short proof-of-concept example?

Answer (score 0):

Just put the access_token string to a hidden field and get the value through javascript and pass it to the JS API Methods.

Comment: The real question is how you pass it to the JS API methods.

Comment: by getting the value of the hidden field and store it into a local javascript variable.

Comment: I found out that it is not possible to pass it to the API call I need to use (UI dialog apprequests), unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
     if (response.authResponse) {
        fbUserId = response.authResponse.userID;
        token = response.authResponse.accessToken;

    } else { 
        fbUserId = 0;
    }
    });

you will get access token
```